# Why doesn't &String automatically become &str in some cases?

Tags: rust

In this toy example I'd like to map the items from a `HashMap<String, String>` with a helper function. There are two versions defined, one that takes arguments of the form `&String` and another with `&str`. Only the `&String` one compiles. I had thought that `String` always dereferences to `&str` but that doesn't seem to be the case here. What's the difference between a `&String` and a `&str`?

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

// &String works
fn process_item_1(key_value: (&String, &String)) -> String {
    let mut result = key_value.0.to_string();
    result.push_str(", ");
    result.push_str(key_value.1);
    result
}

// &str doesn't work (type mismatch in fn arguments)
fn process_item_2(key_value: (&str, &str)) -> String {
    let mut result = key_value.0.to_string();
    result.push_str(", ");
    result.push_str(key_value.1);
    result
}

fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap::new();
    map.insert("a".to_string(), "b".to_string());

    for s in map.iter().map(process_item_2) {  // <-- compile error on this line
        println!("{}", s);
    }
}
```

Here's the error for reference:

```
error[E0631]: type mismatch in function arguments
  --> src/main.rs:23:29
   |
12 | fn process_item_2(key_value: (&str, &str)) -> String {
   | ---------------------------------------------------- found signature of `for<'r, 's> fn((&'r str, &'s str)) -> _`
...
23 |     for s in map.iter().map(process_item_2) {
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected signature of `fn((&String, &String)) -> _`
```

Thanks for your help with a beginner Rust question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It goes even stranger than that:

```rust
map.iter().map(|s| process_item_2(s)) // Does not work
map.iter().map(|(s1, s2)| process_item_2((s1, s2))) // Works
```

The point is that **Rust never performs any expensive coercion**. Converting `&String` to `&str` is cheap: you just take the data pointer and length. But converting `(&String, &String)` to `(&str, &str)` is no so cheap anymore: you have to take the data+length of the first string, then of the second string, then concatnate them together (and also, if it was done for tuple, what about `(((&String, &String, &String), &String), (&String, &String))`? And it was probably done then for arrays too, so what about `&[&String; 10_000]`?) That's why the first closure fails. The second closure, however, destruct the tuple and rebuild it. That means that instead of coercing a tuple, we coerce `&String` twice, and build a tuple from the results. That's fine.

The version without the closure is even more expensive: since you're passing a  function directly to `map()`, and map produces `&String`, someone needs to convert this to `&str`! In order to do that, the compiler would have to introduce a *shim* - a small function that does that works: it takes `(&String, &String)` and calls `process_item_2()` with the `(&String, &String)` coerced to `(&str, &str)`. This is a hidden cost, so Rust (almost) never creates shims. This is why it wouldn't work even for `&String` and not just for `(&String, &String)`. And why `|v| f(v)` is not always the same as `f` - the first one performs coercions, while the second doesn't.